# Log interleaving issue in a multi-threaded application using Spring Boot and asynchronous tasks

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, slf4j

I am working on a Spring Boot application that runs multiple instances of a job called `HeartbeatJob` concurrently. Each `HeartbeatJob` has a producer and a consumer that produce and consume messages respectively.

I have a custom `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with a specified pool size to handle these tasks asynchronously. My problem is that the logs from different threads seem to be interleaved, making it difficult to analyze the logs.

Here is an example of how the logs that are getting mixed up:

```
12:04:22.908 [heartbeatExecutor-3] INFO  com.climate.canarytesting.events.heartbeat.HeartBeatConsumer - The event received by Heartbeat-SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_0 consumer is: {"name": "Heartbeat-SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_1 producer heartbeat message 0"}
12:04:22.908 [heartbeatExecutor-3] INFO  com.climate.canarytesting.events.heartbeat.HeartBeatConsumer - The event received by Heartbeat-SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_0 consumer is: {"name": "Heartbeat-SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_0 producer heartbeat message 0"}
12:04:22.908 [heartbeatExecutor-3] INFO  com.climate.canarytesting.events.heartbeat.HeartBeatConsumer - The event received by Heartbeat-SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_0 consumer is: {"name": "Heartbeat-PRODUCTION_CLUSTER_0 producer heartbeat message 0"}
12:04:22.908 [heartbeatExecutor-3] INFO  com.climate.canarytesting.events.heartbeat.HeartBeatConsumer - The event received by Heartbeat-SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_0 consumer is: {"name": "Heartbeat-PRODUCTION_CLUSTER_1 producer heartbeat message 0"}
12:04:22.908 [heartbeatExecutor-3] INFO  com.climate.canarytesting.events.heartbeat.HeartBeatConsumer - The event received by Heartbeat-SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_0 consumer is: {"name": "Heartbeat-SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_1 producer heartbeat message 1"}
```

The logs should never be receiving a message from outside of its cluster.
So these logs messages look like:

```
The event received by Heartbeat-{cluster} consumer is: {"name": "Heartbeat-{cluster} producer heartbeat message {n}"}
```

Here is the relevant code:

#### `HeartbeatJobConfiguration`

```java
/**
 * This module is responsible for configuring the HeartbeatJob instances and their execution for different clusters.
 * It creates a HeartbeatJob bean and a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean for executing the HeartbeatJobs.
 * The module schedules the execution of HeartbeatJobs for the following clusters:
 * - PRODUCTION_CLUSTER_0
 * - PRODUCTION_CLUSTER_1
 * - SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_0
 * - SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_1
 */

package com.climate.config;

import com.climate.canarytesting.jobs.HeartbeatJob;

import com.climate.eventplatform.client.EventPlatformClientException;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class HeartbeatJobConfiguration {

    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    /**
     * Constructs a new HeartbeatJobConfiguration instance with the provided MeterRegistry.
     *
     * @param meterRegistry the MeterRegistry instance
     */
    @Autowired
    public HeartbeatJobConfiguration(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new HeartbeatJob bean with the provided MeterRegistry.
     *
     * @return a new HeartbeatJob instance
     */
    @Bean
    public HeartbeatJob heartbeatJob() {
        return new HeartbeatJob(meterRegistry);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean for executing HeartbeatJobs.
     *
     * @return a new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor instance
     */
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor heartbeatExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("heartbeatExecutor-");
        return executor;
    }

    // The following scheduled jobs run the HeartbeatJob for different clusters
    // at the specified cron schedule. The HeartbeatJob is responsible for sending
    // and receiving heartbeats for each respective cluster.

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void runProductionCluster0HeartbeatJob() throws EventPlatformClientException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        heartbeatJob().execute("PRODUCTION_CLUSTER_0");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void runProductionCluster1HeartbeatJob() throws EventPlatformClientException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        heartbeatJob().execute("PRODUCTION_CLUSTER_1");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void runSystemsCluster0HeartbeatJob() throws EventPlatformClientException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        heartbeatJob().execute("SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_0");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void runSystemsCluster1HeartbeatJob() throws EventPlatformClientException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        heartbeatJob().execute("SYSTEMS_CLUSTER_1");
    }

}
```

#### `HeartbeatJob`

```java
/**
 * The HeartbeatJob class is responsible for running a scheduled job that
 * sends and receives heartbeats for the configured environment. It also tracks and reports metrics
 * for the job runs using Micrometer.
 */

package com.climate.canarytesting.jobs;

import com.climate.canarytesting.events.heartbeat.HeartBeatConsumer;
import com.climate.canarytesting.events.heartbeat.HeartBeatProducer;
import com.climate.eventplatform.client.EventPlatformClientException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;

import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.text.MessageFormat;


public class HeartbeatJob extends BaseJob {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeartbeatJob.class);
    private String clusterName;
    private final String jobName = "Heartbeat";
    private final Map<String, Counter> totalJobRunsCounters;
    private final Map<String, Counter> successfulJobRunsCounters;

    /**
     * Constructs a new HeartbeatJob instance with the provided meter registry.
     *
     * @param meterRegistry the MeterRegistry instance for reporting metrics
     */
    public HeartbeatJob(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        super(meterRegistry);
        this.totalJobRunsCounters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        this.successfulJobRunsCounters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    /**
     * Executes the heartbeat job on a schedule, sending and receiving heartbeats for the configured environment.
     * It also increments the counters for total job runs and successful job runs.
     *
     * @param clusterName the name of the cluster for which the heartbeat job is executed
     * @throws EventPlatformClientException if there is an error with the event platform client
     * @throws InterruptedException         if the thread is interrupted
     * @throws IOException                  if there is an I/O error
     */
    @Async("heartbeatExecutor")
    public void execute(String clusterName) throws EventPlatformClientException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        this.clusterName = clusterName;
        clusterUrl = setClusterUrlByClusterName(clusterName);

        String counterName;
        counterName = MessageFormat.format("ep.heartbeat.{0}.runs.total", clusterName);
        Counter totalJobRunsCounter = getOrCreateCounter(this.totalJobRunsCounters, counterName);

        counterName = MessageFormat.format("ep.heartbeat.{0}.runs.success", clusterName);
        Counter successfulJobRunsCounter = getOrCreateCounter(this.successfulJobRunsCounters, counterName);

        log.info("{}-{}: incrementing totalJobsRunsCounter", jobName, clusterName);
        totalJobRunsCounter.increment();

        HeartBeatProducer producer = null;
        HeartBeatConsumer consumer = null;

        try {
            log.info("{}-{}: Producer initializing...", jobName, clusterName);
            producer = new HeartBeatProducer(clusterUrl);

            String producerName = MessageFormat.format("{0}-{1} producer", jobName, clusterName);
            producer.produceAll(producerName);
            log.info("{}-{}: Producer terminated...", jobName, clusterName);

            Thread.sleep(5000);

            log.info("{}-{}: Consumer initializing...", jobName, clusterName);
            consumer = new HeartBeatConsumer(clusterUrl);

            String consumerName = MessageFormat.format("{0}-{1} consumer", jobName, clusterName);
            boolean consumed = consumer.consumeUntilTerminated(consumerName);
            log.info("{}-{}: Consumer terminated...", jobName, clusterName);

            if (consumed) {
                log.info("{}-{}: incrementing successfulJobRunsCounter", jobName, clusterName);
                successfulJobRunsCounter.increment();
            }

        } catch (EventPlatformClientException | InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            log.error("{}-{}: Error during job execution. Message: {} {}", jobName, clusterName, e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (producer != null) {
                producer.close();
            }
            if (consumer != null) {
                consumer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### `HeartbeatProducer`

```java
package com.climate.canarytesting.events.heartbeat;

import channels.climate.heartbeat.heartbeat.generated.HeartbeatSchema;
import com.climate.eventplatform.client.EventPlatformClient;
import com.climate.eventplatform.client.EventPlatformClientException;
import com.climate.eventplatform.client.EventPlatformMessage;
import com.climate.eventplatform.client.EventPlatformProducer;
import com.climate.eventplatform.client.EventPlatformOAuth2CredsType;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HeartBeatProducer {

    // Constants
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "climate/heartbeat/heartbeat";
    private static final String EVENT_AVRO_SCHEMA = HeartbeatSchema.getClassSchema().toString();
    private static final int NUM_MESSAGES = 5;
    private static final String TERMINATING_STRING = "##TERMINATE##";
    private static final String SSM_PARAM_TEST_SERVICE_OAUTH2_CREDS = "production.global.event-platform.oauth2creds.sample-applications";
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeartBeatProducer.class);

    // Instance variables
    private static String serviceUrl;
    private EventPlatformClient epClient;
    private EventPlatformProducer<HeartbeatSchema> producer;


    /**
     * Constructs a new instance of the HeartBeatProducer class.
     * @param serviceUrl The URL of the Event Platform service to produce messages to.
     */
    public HeartBeatProducer(String serviceUrl) throws EventPlatformClientException, IOException {
        this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
        this.epClient = new EventPlatformClient(
                serviceUrl,
                EventPlatformOAuth2CredsType.SSM,
                SSM_PARAM_TEST_SERVICE_OAUTH2_CREDS);
        this.producer = new EventPlatformProducer<>(epClient, TOPIC_NAME, EVENT_AVRO_SCHEMA);
    }

    /**
     * Sends a series of heartbeat messages to the Event Platform.
     * @param producerName The name of the producer.
     * @throws EventPlatformClientException if an error occurs while sending the messages.
     * @throws InterruptedException if the thread is interrupted while sleeping.
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public void produceAll(String producerName) throws EventPlatformClientException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        HeartbeatSchema[] heartbeatMessages = new HeartbeatSchema[NUM_MESSAGES + 1]; // add additional spot for TERMINATING_STRING
        heartbeatMessages[0] = new HeartbeatSchema(producerName + " heartbeat message 0");
        heartbeatMessages[1] = new HeartbeatSchema(producerName + " heartbeat message 1");
        heartbeatMessages[2] = new HeartbeatSchema(producerName + " heartbeat message 2");
        heartbeatMessages[3] = new HeartbeatSchema(producerName + " heartbeat message 3");
        heartbeatMessages[4] = new HeartbeatSchema(producerName + " heartbeat message 4");
        heartbeatMessages[5] = new HeartbeatSchema(TERMINATING_STRING);

        for (int i = 0; i < heartbeatMessages.length; i++) {
            EventPlatformMessage<HeartbeatSchema> currentMessage = new EventPlatformMessage<>(heartbeatMessages[i], producerName);
            producer.send(currentMessage);
            log.info("{} sent a message: {}", producerName, currentMessage.getMessageValue());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        if (producer != null) {
            try {
                producer.close();
            } catch ( IOException ex) {
                log.error("Failed to close producer.", ex);
            }
        }
        if (epClient != null) {
            try {
                epClient.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error("Failed to close EventPlatformClient.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### `HeartbeatConsumer`

```java
package com.climate.canarytesting.events.heartbeat;

import channels.climate.heartbeat.heartbeat.generated.HeartbeatSchema;
import com.climate.eventplatform.client.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This class defines a HeartBeatConsumer that is used to consume events from the Event Platform.
 */
public class HeartBeatConsumer {

    // Constants
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "climate/heartbeat/heartbeat";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = "heartbeat_subscription";
    private static final String EVENT_AVRO_SCHEMA = HeartbeatSchema.getClassSchema().toString();
    private static final String SSM_PARAM_TEST_SERVICE_OAUTH2_CREDS = "production.global.event-platform.oauth2creds.sample-applications";
    private static final int ACK_TIMEOUT = 1;
    private static final String terminatingString = "##TERMINATE##";
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeartBeatConsumer.class);

    // Instance variables
    private static String serviceUrl;
    private EventPlatformClient epClient;
    private EventPlatformConsumer<HeartbeatSchema> consumer;

    /**
     * Constructor that initializes a HeartBeatConsumer with a specific service URL.
     *
     * @param serviceUrl the service URL to use
     */
    public HeartBeatConsumer(String serviceUrl) throws EventPlatformClientException, IOException {
        this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
        this.epClient = new EventPlatformClient(
                serviceUrl,
                EventPlatformOAuth2CredsType.SSM,
                SSM_PARAM_TEST_SERVICE_OAUTH2_CREDS);
        this.consumer = new EventPlatformConsumer<>(
                epClient,
                TOPIC_NAME,
                SUBSCRIPTION_NAME,
                EVENT_AVRO_SCHEMA,
                ACK_TIMEOUT,
                EventPlatformSubscriptionInitialPosition.LATEST);
    }

    /**
     * This method consumes events from the Event Platform until a terminating string is received.
     *
     * @param consumerName the name of the consumer
     * @throws IOException if there is an I/O error
     */
    public boolean consumeUntilTerminated(final String consumerName) throws IOException {
        boolean consumed = false;

        try {
            consumed = receiveAndProcessUntilTerminated(consumer, consumerName, terminatingString);
        } catch (EventPlatformClientException ex) {
            log.error("Failed to construct consumer.", ex);
        }

        return consumed;
    }

    /**
     * This method receives events from an EventPlatformConsumer and processes them until a terminating string is received.
     *
     * @param consumer          the EventPlatformConsumer to receive events from
     * @param consumerName      the name of the consumer
     * @param terminatingString the terminating string to look for in the received events
     * @return true if a message was successfully consumed, false otherwise
     * @throws EventPlatformClientException if there is an error receiving or acknowledging an event
     */
    public boolean receiveAndProcessUntilTerminated(
            EventPlatformConsumer<HeartbeatSchema> consumer,
            String consumerName,
            String terminatingString) throws EventPlatformClientException {
        int messageCount = 0;
        boolean consumed = false;

        // The loop exits only on encountering an exception e.g. connection severed, event schema deleted.
        while (true) {
            EventPlatformMessage<HeartbeatSchema> event = consumer.receive();

            log.info("The event received by {} is: {}", consumerName, event.getMessageValue());

            try {
                consumer.acknowledge(event);
                messageCount++;

                // Check if the received event contains the terminating string
                if (event.getMessageValue().toString().contains(terminatingString)) {
                    log.info("{} messages processed.", messageCount);
                    log.info("Terminating string received, exiting.");
                    consumed = true;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (EventPlatformClientException ex) {
                log.error("Failed to acknowledge the event", ex);
                break;
            }
        }
        return consumed;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (consumer != null) {
            try {
                consumer.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error("Failed to close consumer.", ex);
            }
        }
        if (epClient != null) {
            try {
                epClient.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error("Failed to close event platform client.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Things I've tried

- I have found that spacing out the scheduled jobs seems to works. About a 30 second time difference and the logs seem to behave correctly.
- Updated `Logger` variables to from `static` to non-static: `private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeartBeatProducer.class);`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be expected in multhreading processing. Parallel threads will overlap in execution and their logs will overlap in time.

To analyze the log filter by thread identifier.

Spacing in time will surely prevent overlapping, through it can be somewhat unpredictable, and you lose the benefits of multhreading.

Changing the variable to static does nothing for this issue. Better leave it as the log library recommends.